I have a problem with my dark theme in app kotlin
I have a problem with my dark theme, my new Samsung a54 doesn't make dark theme in my app, however old xiaomi and other phones do well and switch to dark theme. I didn't do anything with code. What can be a problem and how to fix it? (I'm using kotlin + xml) android
(https://i.sstatic.net/y9fFY.jpg)
(https://i.sstatic.net/Sch3Q.jpg)
I don't know how to solve it. Please, help me.

Need to see your theme files and maybe the manifest. Are you sure you didn’t use a day/night theme?

Is this happen when you build and run the app? or did you install same APK for both Samsung and xiaomi device? Try installing same APK to Samsung device, that worked in xiaomi device.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
